# Disable api call with list view

Tags: react-admin

It is possible to disable the call of the api in List view when they are no filters values.
I don't want to see the first items of the list when i enter in the list view, but only the result of my request after entering some filters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the data provider and add an exception to handle your specific case, for example:

```
const restProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api/');

const dataProvider = (type, resource, params) => new Promise(resolve => {
    if (
        type === 'GET_LIST' &&
        resource === 'resource_name' &&
        Object.keys(params).length === 0
    ) {
        return resolve({ data: [] });
    }

    return resolve(restProvider(type, resource, params));
});
```